# Down arrow key button for HTML page

Tags: javascript, html

I have an application that requires the down arrow, or the letter `s` for a specific function (both down arrow and the letter "s" trigger the function in the application).

The user cannot use the keyboard so I have to make a button on screen for the user to click. The application is displayed in an HTML page and I have made other buttons with the following code:

```
<img src="left.jpg" name="Left" onclick="javascript:[CODE_TO_RUN];" vspace="0" width="75" height="75" hspace="0" />
```

This works for my other functions but I cannot get sendKey to work to simulate the down arrow or the "s" key. Does anyone know how to make a button on an HTML page that will simulate pressing the down arrow or the "s" key? Please help, thank you!

Comment: Where is the HTML page running?

Comment: Why can't you simply call the same Javascript code that the keypress handler calls?

Comment: Also get rid of that "javascript:" stuff. It's unnecessary in an "onclick" attribute (and really anywhere else you *should* be putting Javascript code).

Comment: Except for one situation: IE with VBScript as the first piece of script on the page. Granted real JS folks will not have encountered this, but that is where it is needed on all event handlers on the page

Answer (score 0):

You wrote "sendKey", I only know this as a method of the windows-shell. Does this mean, that it only has to work on MSIE?

If yes, you cant usually access the shell there because of security-restrictions, but you can fire an event.
Example:

```
//create event-object
e = document.createEventObject();
//set keycode to 115(for s)
e.setAttribute('keyCode',115);
//fire on document
document.fireEvent('onkeypress',e);
```

To do similar in other browsers, you find here a tutorial:
http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/javascript/domevents

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to do this in general. Firefox can be made to fully simulate some key events with associated browser behaviour; other browsers can programmatically fire key events but will not perform the usual browser action associated with the event, such as displaying a character.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a good workaround if I understood you question correctly:

Using jQuery animate() function to do a smooth scrolling:
I have also created a div as follow:

```
<div id="scrollToHere">
Scroll to here
</div>
```

You need something to run your script. Create a button like this:

The jQuery Code will be like this:

```
function scrollWin(){
$('html, body').animate({
scrollTop: $("#scrollToHere").offset().top
}, 2000);
}
```

Resource:

http://blog.freelancer-id.com/index.php/2009/03/26/scroll-window-smoothly-in-jquery

You could make scroll "buttons" always visible!

Good luck, not sure if I understood your question, please tell me if otherwise!